# A misunderstanding of Donsker's theorem and a contradictory "proof"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion, weak-convergence, central-limit-theorem

In [excercise 2.4 of these lectures notes on Donsker's theorem](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Edavar/ps-pdf-files/donsker.pdf), it is stated that for a sum $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ of i.i.d random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$, and for any continuous bounded function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f \left( \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \to \int_0^1 ds \ f(W(s)), \ N \to \infty,$$
where $W(s)$ is a standard Brownian motion, and the limit is understood as a weak limit.

However, I feel that I have a contradictory "proof" of a different limit, and I cannot quite understand what is going wrong.

By [Skorohod's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_representation_theorem), there exists probability triple $(\Omega', \mathcal{F}', \mathbb{P}')$, and a collection of random variables $\{Y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $Y_\infty$, such that $Y_n \to Y$ almost surely, and
$$ \mathbb{P}'(Y_n \leq x) = \mathbb{P} \left( \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \leq x \right), \ \mathbb{P}(Y_\infty \leq x) = \mathbb{P}(G \leq x),$$
where $G$ is a standard Gaussian.

Let $f,g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any continuous bounded functions. Since $Y_n \to Y_\infty$ almost surely, by continuity of $f$, it follows that $f(Y_n) \to f (Y_\infty)$ almost surely, and, because the mean of a convergent sequence converges to the limit of the sequence, we also have
$$  \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f \left( Y_n \right) \to f (Y_\infty) .$$
Because $g$ is continous and bounded, we can apply dominated convergence from which we get
$$ \mathbb{E}'g \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f \left( Y_n \right)\right) \to \mathbb{E}' g \left(f (Y_\infty) \right) .$$
Now, by using the fact that the $Y_n$ and $Y_\infty$ are the same in law as the scaled sums, we have
$$ \lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{E}g \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f \left( \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \mathbb{E}'g \left( \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f \left( Y_n \right)\right) = \mathbb{E}' g \left(f (Y_\infty) \right) = \mathbb{E} g \left( f(G) \right) .$$
This would imply that
$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N f \left( \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \to f(G), \ N \to \infty, $$
weakly, but this seems to be in contradiction with the earlier presented result. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skorohod Representation Theorem only tells you that $Y_n$ has the same distribution as $\frac {S_n} {\sqrt n}$ for each fixed $n$ and it says nothing about joint distributions of the $Y_n$'s. So you cannot say that $\frac 1 N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} f(\frac {S_n} {\sqrt n})$ has the same distribution as $\frac 1 N \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} f(Y_n)$.